# Lawful possession and transport of a firearm without a permit on foot in Florida?

Tags: united-states, florida

Lets say Bob goes out to the gun range with a friend. They drove to the gun range. Bobs friend has an emergency and leaves Bob stranded. Bob has no one to who can pick him up. Bob wants to go from point A (Gun Range) to point B (Home) on foot. Bob has a obvious gun bag in which he puts his weapons away. Is there any lawful way Bob can walk home with his guns without a concealed weapons permit in Florida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Florida law has a general prohibition on carrying firearms in public without a license, whether concealed or openly. However, a  number of broad exceptions are carved out in [790.25(3)](http://flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2013/Chapter790/All), including 790.25(3)(j):

> (3) LAWFUL USES.—The provisions of ss. 790.053 and 790.06 do not apply in the following instances, and, despite such sections, it is lawful for the following persons to own, possess, and lawfully use firearms and other weapons, ammunition, and supplies for lawful purposes: [...]
>
> (j) A person firing weapons for testing or target practice under safe conditions and in a safe place not prohibited by law or going to or from such place;

Assuming that the gun range was "a safe place not prohibited by law" and that the target practice was conducted under "safe conditions", Bob is protected by this provision because he is going from such a place.  It appears to me that this applies whether the weapon is concealed or not.

Of course, it is entirely possible he will be questioned by the police, who would have no way of knowing (until he tells them) that he was in fact going from the gun range and thus is in compliance with the law.